# Use of unresolved identifier 'PFUser' - Swift/Xcode/Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to query the users in my Parse DB into my Table View Controller in my app in Xcode.

I am a beginner, but I have posted my code snippet from my added .swift file to my project.  I am trying to query the user in the .swift file but it is not recognizing 'PFUser' from my View Controller.

Do I need to declare the PFUser as something in my .swift file before first calling it in my ViewDidLoad method?

Any ideas?

Code snippet: [image: Code snippet]

Comment: First and foremost if you want us to help you, type out your code!

Comment: Also, please include the specifics on the error you are receiving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the Parse-Framework in your project. [Check this quickstart-guide how to do it](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing).

If you've done it already, you need to import Parse in your File like that:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
```

Like you/Xcode has already done that with the UIKit.

Comment: Thank you :) your answer helps me.

Answer (score 2):

1. First put Parse SDK into the folder into your project navigator area of Xcode.
2. You will get a Dialogue, You will need to check the box that says copy items if needed and then click Finish.
3. The next thing we need to do to connect our Swift app to parse.com is create a bridging header. To do this you need to create a new File (File -> New -> File) of type Objective-C File. Call this whatever you like. Here I have just called it testDataCustom. You will see another Dialogue that looks like having this Line at the top "Would you like to configure Objective C bridging Header?"  Click on Yes.
4. Now it will add some new files to your project. Click on the File:     testData-Bridging-Header.h. You should see this:

   ```
    // Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
   ```

5.Underneath this comment code we need to add an #import so that our project knows to use the Parse iOS SDK. To do this we simply add a line into this file, like so:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

---

Now you can successfully use Parse methods and properties.
Referred from this [Link](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/connect-your-swift-application-to-parse-com/?utm_source=internalLink&utm_medium=internalLink&utm_term=internalLink&utm_content=internalLink&utm_campaign=internalLink)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the proper Parse file. :)

I don't know Swift but I assume that of you type

```
 Import Parse.h
```

It will autocomplete for you.

From what I know in objective-c, you might need to import

```
Import <Parse\Parse.h>
```

Comment: You should have been able to find that out by yourself, just by googling the error ! But I'm glad we have found a solution :)

Comment: I am following through a tutorial guide on this specific app and he completely skipped over that part, so it left me in a pickle!  Thanks so much!

Comment: In swift you are not supposed to import .h files. Only in bridging header.